# Kubernetes on gcp for Nodejs and Mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I want to deploy cluster of nodejs with mongodb replication set on gcp with the help of kubernetes, till now I am able to deploy nodejs cluster on gcp with kubernetes and mongodb replication set separately with the help of this 
[pkdone/gke-mongodb](https://github.com/pkdone/gke-mongodb-demo).

Can anyone help me or provide me a link of any tutorial or documentation.

Comment: Such questions are frowned upon at SO, sorry. Please read the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) before asking a question: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 0):

This example here on Kubernete's official Github account shows in details how to create your cluster on GCP with a NodeJS web service and a MongoDB instance.

https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/tree/master/staging/nodesjs-mongodb

This other post by @jaydestro was very helpful for me. It covers in details the whole process using MongoDB Atlas.

https://medium.com/google-cloud/modern-distributed-application-deployment-with-kubernetes-and-mongodb-atlas-4ec9eff5bab2

Comment: Rather than posting links to external resources, could you include the relevant pieces in your answer?